# Rails 6: How to associate specific stylesheet and external js plugin to a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on Ruby on Rails 6. My application has a controller that uses a different layout called "special":

```
class BoxController < ApplicationController
  layout "special"
  ...
end
```

So I've created a new layouts/special.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "special" %>
  <%= javascript_link_tag "special" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
 <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I then placed my 3rd party css and plugin under vendor->stylesheets and javascript folder:

```
stylesheets
  -monnom.css
  -mintymon.css

javascript
  -monnom.js
  -mintymon.js
```

I tried this but did not read my css and js.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing in order for this work?

Can anyone guide me step by step? a super beginner here.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of the `special` stylesheet(app/assets/stylesheets/special) and  javascript(app/assets/javascript/special.js)

Comment: I am only importing vendor->stylesheets and javascript folder: on those files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With Asset Pipeline:**

1. Create a `special.js` file in the `app/assets/javascripts` folder.
2. Add JS files to `special.js`

   ```
   //= require monnom
   //= require mintymon
   ```
3. Create a `special.css(.scss)` file in the `app/assets/stylesheets` folder.
4. Add CSS files to `special.css(.scss)`

   ```
   @import "monnom";
   @import "mintymon";
   ```
5. If it doesn't work like this, add a custom path into `config.assets.paths` so the autoloader can find them

   ```
   // assets.rb
   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "javascripts") // I think the folder name should be javascipts instead of javascript
   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "stylesheets")
   ```

   Then **restart** `rails server`

   You can see a list of `load paths`. Use `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` command in `rails c`.